# clSetKernelArg changed arg_value from 16 to 140733193388048?

Tags: c, osx-snow-leopard, opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm delving into OpenCL by making a Matrix dot product implementation. I'm having a problem with getting my kernels to return the same values as my host.

I have made an encapsulation function that allocates device memory, sets parameters to a kernel, runs the kernel and returns the result back to the host.

```
 /* This function runs the matrix dot product on whatever OpenCL device 
  * you specify 
  */
cl_int OpenCL_MatrixMul(cl_device_id * device, cl_context * context, 
    cl_command_queue * commandQueue, cl_kernel * matrixMulKernel, float * A_h, 
    float * B_h, float * C_h, const cl_uint HeightA, const cl_uint WidthB, 
    const cl_uint WidthAHeightB)
{
    printf("Inside matrix mul, WidthA: %zu, WidthB: %zu, WidthAHeightB: %zu\n", 
        HeightA, WidthB, WidthAHeightB);

    //this error variable will record any errors found and will be returned 
    //by this function
    cl_int error = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_int clEnqueueReadBuffer_error;

    //declare a place for the memory on the device, A is the A matrix, 
    //B is the B matrix, C is the C result matrix
    cl_mem A_d, B_d, C_d;               
    //this is a temporary value for holding the maximum work group size
    size_t maximum_local_ws;

    //variable for holding the number of work items per group
    size_t local_ws[2]; 
    //variable for holding the number of work items              
    size_t global_ws[2];            

    //calcuate work group and local size
    //get the maximum work group size for the kernel, i.e. set local_ws
    clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo((* matrixMulKernel), (* device), 
        CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(maximum_local_ws), 
        &maximum_local_ws, NULL);

    //find the largest integer, power of 2, square root, for maximum_local_ws 
    //that is less than or equal to 16
    for(size_t i = 1; (i * i) <= maximum_local_ws && i <= maxBlockSize; i *= 2)
    {
        local_ws[0] = i;
        local_ws[1] = i;
    }
    //calculate global work size
    global_ws[0] = WidthB;  
    global_ws[1] = HeightA;

    printf("Work group size calculated.\n");

    //Allocate global memory on the device
    //put A on the device
    A_d = clCreateBuffer ((* context), CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
        (WidthAHeightB * HeightA * sizeof(float)), A_h, &error);    
    //put B on the device   
    B_d = clCreateBuffer ((* context), CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
        (WidthB * WidthAHeightB * sizeof(float)), B_h, &error);
    //create a space for C on the device        
    C_d = clCreateBuffer ((* context), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 
        (HeightA * WidthB * sizeof(float)), NULL, &error);              

    printf("Global memory allocated.\n");

    if(error == CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        //set the prarameters of the kernels
        //Put in A
        error  = clSetKernelArg((* matrixMulKernel), 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &A_d);
        //Put in B                                                  
        error |= clSetKernelArg((* matrixMulKernel), 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &B_d);
        //Put in C                                  
        error |= clSetKernelArg((* matrixMulKernel), 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &C_d);                          
        //Put in HeightA
        error |= clSetKernelArg((* matrixMulKernel), 3, sizeof(cl_uint), 
            &HeightA);                              
        //Put in WidthB
        error |= clSetKernelArg((* matrixMulKernel), 4, sizeof(cl_uint), 
            &WidthB);                               
        //Put in WidthAHeightB
        error |= clSetKernelArg((* matrixMulKernel), 5, sizeof(cl_uint),
            &WidthAHeightB);                        

        printf("Parameters added to the kernel.\n");

        if(error == CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            //execute the kernel
            printf("Running Kernel, Local work size: %zu x %zu global worksize: 
            %zu x %zu, HeightA: %zu, WidthB: %zu, WidthAHeightB: %zu\n", 
                local_ws[0], local_ws[1], global_ws[0], global_ws[1], 
                HeightA, WidthB, WidthAHeightB);
            error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel((* commandQueue),   
                (* matrixMulKernel), 1, NULL, global_ws, local_ws, 0, NULL, 
                NULL);

                printf("Kernel Ran.\n");

            if(error == CL_SUCCESS)
            {
                 printf("Kernel Launched Successfully\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Kernel Not Launched\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Parameters not added to the kernel.\n");
    }
    printf("Reading results back from device\n");

    //read the result back to the host system, (copy C_h to C_d)
    clEnqueueReadBuffer_error = clEnqueueReadBuffer((* commandQueue), C_d,  
        CL_TRUE, 0, HeightA * WidthB * sizeof(float), C_h, 0, NULL, NULL);

    //make sure we don't write over previous errors, if 
    //clEnqueueReadBuffer_error has an error
    if(error == CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        error = clEnqueueReadBuffer_error;
    }

    printf("Freeing device memory\n");

    //Free global memory on the device
    clReleaseMemObject(A_d);
    clReleaseMemObject(B_d);
    clReleaseMemObject(C_d);

    return error;
}
```

This code, when run, it outputs something strange:

> Inside matrix mul, WidthA: 16, WidthB: 16, WidthAHeightB: 16
>   Work group size calculated.
>   Global memory allocated.
>   Parameters added to the kernel.
>   Running Kernel, Local work size: 1 x 1 global worksize: 16 x 16, HeightA: 16, WidthB: 140733193388048, WidthAHeightB: 16
>   Kernel Ran.
>   Kernel Launched Successfully
>   Reading results back from device
>   Freeing device memory

For some reason, widthB changed its value from 16 to 140733193388048. The strange thing is, widthB is different, yet WidthA and WidthAHeightB, despite being used the same way, remain the same. Furthermore, the value 140733193388048 remains unusually deterministic throughout all the calls I give to it.

Consequently, the first row, of the matrix, that my device returns, is the same as the host, but the subsequent values are not.

I'm programming on Mac OS X using Apple's OpenCL implementation in Snow Leopard.

What is going on here, and how do you keep something like this from happening?

Comment: This is indeed strange, the standard guarantees that the values are copied and the memory pointed to is left intact. By the way, you don't need to pass `cl_foo` as pointers to the function if you don't intend to change them. In the `cl.h` header, they are always defined as pointers to structures.

Comment: @matthias I put in printf statements, that print out widthB infront of and after the offending, inaccurate print out line for WidthB. The output was: WidthB: 16
Running Kernel, Local work size: 1 x 1 global worksize: 16 x 16, HeightA: 16, WidthB: 140733193388048, WidthAHeightB: 16
WidthB: 16
My big question is: what?

Comment: You pass cl_uint (32-bit unsigned) values to %zu expecting size_t. Try %u, or cast them to size_t.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why my kernel wasn't returning the right answer was because I wasn't giving clEnqueueNDRangeKernel the right number of dimensions for the work group. I'm still getting the weird outputs for WidthB, which isn't comforting knowing my print outs won't be accurate if I want to try to debug my programs.